# Toggle the class of another element inside 'this'

Tags: javascript, html

I got an accordion code from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) but I'd like to replace a class of an `icon <i>`.

How may I `switchClass()` of a element within `this` on this code?

Code from W3Schools:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("course-row");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("unit-row-hide");
    }
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="row-history">
    <div class="row course-row active">
        <div class="course-name col-md-4">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <a href="https://www.xxx.com.br/curso-teste-4">Curso Teste 4</a>
        </div>
        <div class="course-progress col-md-2">
            <div class="course-progress-bar-wrapper col-md-8">
                <div class="course-progress-bar">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="course-progress-percent col-md-4">100%</div>
        </div>
        <div class="course-remaining col-md-2">Completo</div>
        <div class="course-timestamp col-md-2">21 horas atrás</div>
        <div class="course-remove col-md-2"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div> <!--  .course-row -->

    <div class="unit-row">

        <div class="row single-unit">
            <div class="unit-name col-md-4">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Curso Teste 4 - Unidade 3
            </div>
            <div class="unit-nbsp col-md-4">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="unit-timestamp col-md-2">21 horas atrás</div>
            <div class="unit-remove col-md-2"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>

    </div> <!--  .unit-row -->
</div>
```

I need to replace the class `fa-caret-right` from `<i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>` to `fa-caret-down` when the div is collapsed and back to `fa-caret-right` when it is not collapsed.

Comment: So, the problem is that you don't know how to get a reference to that element?

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, I need to target that `<i>` to `switchClass()`, but I need to use the same script.

Comment: If it's always the first grandchild, you could use `this.children[0].children[0]` to refer to it. More reliable might be [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). There are basically two ways to get a reference to an element: tree traversal or search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already use the appropriate function: `classList.toggle()`. Just select the `<i>` element and apply the function on it for both classes:

```
var fa = this.getElementsByTagName("i")[0];
fa.classList.toggle("fa-caret-right");
fa.classList.toggle("fa-caret-down");
```

The first one removes the right arrow, the second one adds the down arrow. On the next click it is vice versa (toggled).

Comment: I just edited 'cause I saw that toggle() cannot be used on the return value of itself, so we need a second line.